# Is there an independant SSO system with privacy at the core?

Tags: web-apps, web, web-services, phone, app

I would like a Single Sign On system that is not one of the big tech companies.
Maybe based on web 3.0 or some other more privacy concerned player like Firefox or Brave browser on the web.

I don't see the option on many websites, or Wifi login screens - but SurfShark started offering a "Alternative ID" service recently, which is somewhat useful for what I am looking for.

But I really want a SSO tool that is as easy to implement for webmasters as Stripe (or the big tech co's) but puts a layer between my actual information and the website owner.

I am looking for way more granular control over them knowing anything about me at all. Maybe first name and location only all the way to full verified ID and address depending on the site.

There is no reason that a Wifi login screen needs all that information, and they don't even verify it, so you can put anything you want in the login screen.

I regularly use something like this:
Fname: no
Lname: way
Email: YouAre@GettingMy.Email
haha

But I would prefer a SSO button that shares
Fname: Craig
Verified status: Full
IF even required:
Email: thesite@me.ssoservice.com

Some of the form filling services, or even the browser could save your "Alternative ID" or a single use email address.

But, is there a service that does this all for you, and could quickly proliferate across web owners. Surely I am not the only one that wants my information to stay mine?